# Jacobian of transformation

Tags: integration

Let's have integral
$$
I = \int \int f(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)d^{3}xd^{3}y
$$
Let's use transformation 
$$
\mathbf x = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf \alpha + \mathbf \beta), \quad \mathbf y = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf \alpha - \mathbf \beta )
$$
What's the jacobian of given transformation? I've got $\frac{1}{32}$,
$$
\left|\frac{\partial (\mathbf x,  \mathbf y )}{\partial (\mathbf \alpha , \mathbf \beta)}\right| = 2\left|\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}^{2}\right| =\frac{1}{32},
$$ 
but the correct result is $\frac{1}{8}$. How to show it?

Comment: Why those $3$ exponents ? Why a $3\times3$ array ? Why the square of the array ? Why the factor $2$ ? Why $\mathbf x$ and $x$ ? Why only diagonal terms ??

Comment: "...Why those 3 exponents ?..", - what did you mean? "Why the factor 2 ?", - I thought that each element of matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial (\mathbf x, \mathbf y)}{\partial (\alpha , \beta )}\end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to $3 \times 3$ matrix (such as $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha}$ is 3-dimensional matrix). Then the determinant of these 2*2 matrix contains two summands $\frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial \alpha}\frac{\partial \mathbf y}{\partial \beta}$, which are diagonal due to transformation law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the Jacobian given by:
$$J=\left|\dfrac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (\alpha,\beta)}\right|=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha}&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \beta}\\\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \beta}\end{vmatrix}$$
In which case you clearly have:
$$J=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}\\\dfrac{1}{2}&-\dfrac{1}{2}\end{vmatrix}=\left|-\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4}\right|=\dfrac{1}{2}$$
which is the Jacobian of the transformation along one component of the vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. Cube this to account for the 3 dimensions of your vectors, and you get the expected result.

(Cheers, `Hrodelbert`)

Comment: The Jacobian is defined positive, which solves the sign problem. Also, you ignored the fact that $x,y$ are three dimensional coordinates, which leads to $J=1/2^3=1/8$

Comment: @Hrodelbert Didn't see the bold face vectors, thank you :)

Comment: @Demostene glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$ 
 \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(\alpha, \beta)}
  = \frac 12 \begin{pmatrix}
        \def\Id{\mathrm{id}_3}\Id & -\Id\\ \Id & \Id     
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Hence
$$ \det \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(\alpha, \beta)}
  = \frac 1{2^6} \det\begin{pmatrix}
        \def\Id{\mathrm{id}_3}\Id & -\Id\\ \Id & \Id     
    \end{pmatrix}
  = \frac 1{2^6} \det\begin{pmatrix} \Id & -\Id\\ 0 & 2\Id 
    \end{pmatrix}
  = \frac 1{2^6} \cdot 8
  = \frac 18
$$

Comment: What is $id_{3}$ and what's is origin?